# problem installing MS Office2010 (64 bit) in Ubuntu 14.04 Wine

Tags: software-installation, wine, microsoft-office

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I could not install MS Office 2010 or any office version using wine. A message pop up says "Office encountered an error during setup" but other *.exe files run perfectly. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

MS Office 2010 (64-bit) does not work on wine. Here are other options **(in no specific order)**.

1. **Install 32-bit version**
   The 32-bit version works alright on wine. Try installing that. You can also try installing a latter version (2007, 2003 etc). Check out the list at https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=31.
2. **Install Other Office program**
   There are other great software that you can use in place of MS Office. Here's a list of some popular ones.

   - Libre Office
   - Apache Open Office
   - Google Docs (web based)
3. **Use CrossOver**
   CrossOver is your average wine platform tweaked to support a lot of programs and games. Check out the full list at https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/.
   *Reversal:* It's not free you have to pay for it though you can try it for a few days.
4. **Virtualization**
   Put your whole MS Windows OS inside Ubuntu and then install your MS Office on that.

   - VirtualBox:

     > $sudo apt-get install virtualbox-qt
   - VmWare:
     It's not free. You have to pay for it, but like CrossOver you can get a free trial.
5. **PlayOnLinux**
   A frontend to wine - *minus all the headache of some configuring on wine*. Easier to use than wine because it install some of the software or libraries that may be needed by whatever program you wish to install

   > $sudo apt-get install playonlinux